# Rewrite font URLs in a nrwl/nx React js project

Tags: webpack, sass, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I have a nrwl/nx React generated app with SCSS used for styling. When importing font or image files within SCSS, the compiled SCSS assumes that fonts/images will live in the same directory.

**Example SCSS:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "X";
  src: url("./assets/fonts/X.woff");
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

**Compiled SCSS:**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "boreal";
  **src: url("x.woff");**
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Notice that the font URL got rewritten to fetch in the same directory as the stylesheet.

Is there a way to rewrite CSS URLs? Much like using publicUrls in plain Webpack?

I have tried using file-loader to attempt to rename the font URLs to no avail.

**Project.json:**

```
"targets" : {
   "build": {
     // ...
     "webpackConfig": "apps/my-application/webpack.config.js"
   }
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
module.exports = (config, context) => {
  nrwlConfig(config);
  return {
    ...config,
    module: {
      ...config.module,
      rules: [
        ...config.module.rules,
        {
          loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
          test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)?$/,
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]',
            publicPath: '../../custom-folder',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working in a project with similar technologies (Nx, webpack and Sass) and the solution I used to solve this problem was "importing" my local fonts on my index.html, you should follow the next steps for this approach:

1. Create a "fonts" folder with your fonts files.
2. In ./fonts create a .css file exporting and formatting the fonts

   @font-face {
   font-family: Lato;
   src: url('Lato-Regular.woff') format('woff')
   }
3. Use  tag on ./index.html to use your localFonts in your project.

```
<link rel='preload' href='/assets/fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.woff' as='font' type='font/woff' crossorigin>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/assets/fonts/Lato/lato.css' as='style'>
```

4. create un your root sass file, a variable to save that font.

```
:root {
      --base-font: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    }
```

And that's all, I hope this can solve your issue.